# using co and promises from sync code (mongoDB example)

Tags: javascript, promise, generator, co

How do I use co() wrapped functions to integrate with normal synchronous code?

For example I have `co.wrap`ped this function that uses yield to call an async method on mongo:

```
let wrap = co.wrap(function* (collName) {
  debug("collName", collName);
  let collection = AppConfig.db.collection(collName);
  let res = yield collection.findOne({});
  debug("res", res);
  yield res;
});
```

which is being called with this:

```
//
class TopicsResponse {

  public static topics(bot, message) {
    let topic = wrap("Topics");
    debug("topic", topic);
    topic.then( function() {
      debug("topic.then", topic);
      bot.reply(message, "topics:" + topic.cname);
    });
  }
//
}
```

which gives a log like below:

`TopicsResponse collName +3s Topics
  TopicsResponse topic +2ms Promise { <pending> }
  TopicsResponse res +1ms { _id: 56d6bdd93cf89d4082e1bd27,
  cname: 'nodejs',
  username: 'bob' }
  TopicsResponse topic.then +1ms Promise { undefined }`

So inside the `co.wrapped` method, the res has real data: `{ cname: nodejs }` etc. But what it returns/yields back is undefined.

I think this is something to do with the generator function yielding a promise..

I also tried just

```
yield collection.findOne({});
```

which returns

```
Promise { undefined }
```

Is it possible to use co this way to make what would be async code look/run like sync code? Other examples I've seen just put everything inside co() at the top level, eg http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#find

Update, this works using promises:

```
let getTopic = co.wrap(function* (collName) {
  debug("collName", collName);
  let collection = AppConfig.db.collection(collName);
  let res = yield collection.findOne({});
  debug("res", res);  // prints correctly
  return res;
  // yield res;
});



//
class TopicsResponse {

  public static topics(bot, message) {
    let topic = getTopic("Topics");
    debug("topic", topic);
    topic.then( function(doc) {
      debug("doc", doc);
      debug("topic.then", topic);
      bot.reply(message, "topics:" + doc.cname);
    });
  }
//
}
```

But I want to push all the ugly promise wrapping `.then()` code into the library, and not have to sprinkle it all over my app...

Comment: Did you mean `return res` in the generator function?

Comment: actually yes, return res gives back the promise, but it's still a promise. i guess there's no way to get at the result (promise resolution?)

Comment: `res` is not a promise - `findOne(…)` is one. `topic` will be another promise, and `doc` the result value. There's no other way to get at the result than wrapping your generator code in `co` or to use `then` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

No, once you "dirty" up your code with promises it has to be promises all the way (it's the same way with callbacks).

You have to wrap *everything* with a `co(` call. This will also behave this way with async functions when those land.

This is not an "artifact" or design issue - it is actually really useful as it can show you what parts of your code are asynchronous and what are not.

If you wrap everything in `co` you have explicit code - but not ugly code. You know exactly which methods do and which methods don't perform I/O.